# Android Hilt ViewModel not working when shrinkResources true

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm using Android Hilt ViewModel. It's working fine for debug mode below:

```
debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```

but when I change to release mode, Android Hilt not working. Especially when I change shrinkResources to true or debuggable to false, It's will not working. Below is my release mode:

```
release { 
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

Below is my proguard:

> -dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
> -keepnames @dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

Please help me!

Comment: what is your version android-hilt ?

Comment: android-hilt version 2.40.1"

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: I cannot see locate, beacuse it's not working when debuggable = false.

Comment: I just know that when I open the Splash screen, I have Intent to the new screen

Comment: Can you share the logs if there are any warnings or errors?